# How do I add big HTTP files in a Dockerfile and exclude them from image layers?

Tags: curl, docker, nexus, dockerfile

Our [Nexus server](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/product-overview) provides build artifacts for our Java project including its installer. That installer is **really big** (>1GB). I would like to retrieve and use it in a `Dockerfile`.

What I did so far is the following:

```
FROM debian:jessie
...
RUN apt-get install -y curl xmllib-xpath-perl
ENV PROJECT_VERSION x.y.z-SNAPSHOT
...
RUN VERSION=`curl --silent "http://nexus:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=public&g=my.group.id&a=installer&v=${PROJECT_VERSION}&e=sh&c=linux64" | xpath -q -s '' -e '//data/version/text()'` \
    && echo Version:\'${VERSION}\' \
    && curl --silent http://nexus/content/groups/public/my/group/id/installer/${PROJECT_VERSION}/installer-${VERSION}-linux64.sh \
        --create-dirs \
        --output ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh \
    && sh ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh <someArgs> \
    && rm ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh
...
```

With that approach I am able to:

- Query Nexus to provide the latest SNAPSHOT version for the provided `${PROJECT_VERSION}` which is logged out during `docker build`
- Use that version to download the corresponding installer binary
- Execute the installer binary
- Delete the installer binary immediately after execution to **not have it stored within the created Docker image layer**

What is missing:

- Whenever a new installer gets deployed to Nexus I have to build the Docker image with `docker build --no-cache`. Otherwise Docker is not able to **invalidate its cache** and re-run the installation step for a newer installer that was meanwhile deployed to Nexus.

So I tried a different approach using the `ADD` statement as those have **caching capabilities** according to the documentation. But that does not work since I need to provide a parameter to the `ADD` statement that is set by a previous step querying Nexus for the correct SNAPSHOT version:

```
FROM debian:jessie
...
RUN apt-get install -y curl xmllib-xpath-perl
ENV PROJECT_VERSION x.y.z-SNAPSHOT
...
ADD http://nexus:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=public&g=my.group.id&a=installer&v=${PROJECT_VERSION}&e=sh&c=linux64 ${INSTALL_DIR}/version.xml
RUN cat ${INSTALL_DIR}/version.xml | xpath -q -s '' -e '//data/version/text()' > ${INSTALL_DIR}/version.txt

# FIXME: Somehow do a `cat ${INSTALL_DIR}/version.txt to set the ENV ${VERSION} variable ?!

ADD http://nexus/content/groups/public/my/group/id/installer/${PROJECT_VERSION}/installer-${VERSION}-linux64.sh ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh
RUN ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh <someArgs> && rm ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh
...
```

That approach does not work because:

- It is not possible to set the `${VERSION}` environment variable within the `Dockerfile` to the version stored within the `version.txt` file.
- It is not possible to prevent having the installer stored within an image layer.

But at least this would use proper caching to re-use existing image layers for old installer versions and create new ones whenever a new installer version on Nexus gets deployed.

**So the question is**: How do I enable proper caching, cache invalidation and exclusion of the big installer file from the Docker image layers at the same time?

**EDIT**: I found a way to get the caching of image layers working properly by using an other Nexus API:

```
FROM debian:jessie
...
ENV PROJECT_VERSION x.y.z-SNAPSHOT
...
ADD http://nexus:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r=public&g=my.group.id&a=installer&v=${PROJECT_VERSION}&e=sh&c=linux64 ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh
RUN sh ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh <someArgs> \
    && rm ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh
...
```

But still the **problem of having a very big installer file included in the image layers remains** since in that code snipped the `ADD` mechanism is used.

Any ideas about how to benefit from the caching and its correct invalidation provided by the `ADD` statement but at the same time not include the added file into the images history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing curl/wget, install and remove in one long run command?

**Update** in combination with `ADD` of a smaller resource, see TC's detailed answer.

Comment: I did that already. Please have a look at the first code snippet of my question. In that case image layer caching does not work. The download step will never be executed again in further builds unless I rebuild every layer again with 'docker build --no-cache ...'.

Comment: my bad, didn't read properly at the beginning. I guess sticking to the  released versions is not an option? Aren't there md5 or some other hashes published with your artifact? You could then ADD them, forcing new RUN if the checksum has changed.

Comment: That is what the ADD already does. It checks the HTTP last modified header. Only when the file is modified since the last download it executes a new ADD. Otherwise it takes the cached layer. But still the problem with the huge downloaded file in the image layers remain in that case.

Comment: if you have control over the release process, you could add a small artifact which would contain a timestamp of the build or a downloadable checksum file. Then you would ADD this small artifact, and do the RUN curl/install/remove cycle on changes detected.

Comment: something like this plugin: http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/examples/generating-project-artifacts-checksums.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that idea. That helped me to find a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

I accepted [Mykola Gurov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243861/mykola-gurov)s answer because in one of his comments he pointed out an idea that helped me to solve this issue.

Here is what I did to have proper caching and cache invalidation as well as having the big installer file excluded:

```
FROM debian:jessie
...
RUN apt-get install -y curl
ENV PROJECT_VERSION x.y.z-SNAPSHOT
...
ADD http://nexus:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=public&g=my.group.id&a=installer&v=${PROJECT_VERSION}&e=sh&c=linux64 ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.xml
RUN curl --silent "http://nexus:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r=public&g=my.group.id&a=installer&v=${PROJECT_VERSION}&e=sh&c=linux64" \
        --output ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh \
    && sh ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh <someArgs> \
    && rm ${INSTALL_DIR}/installer.sh
...
```

The first `ADD` downloads the Maven metadata for the requested artifact. That XML file is quite small. It uses proper caching so whenever the metadata on the Nexus has been modified the cache gets invalidated.

The `ADD` and all its following instructions are executed without re-using any cached versions in that case.

If the metadata on the server did not change since the last download the `ADD` and the following `RUN` instruction which executes `curl` are taken from the image layer cache. And in the `RUN` it is possible to download, execute and remove the temporary big installer file in one step without having it stored in any image layers.